# Binding ListBox Item Index

Tags: vb.net, xaml, binding, listbox

I have a ListBox in a ToolBAr with images.
I want to bind the selected item with a property "SelectedLockView"

```
    <ToolBar   Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolBar}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <ListBox Height="50"  x:Name="ListBoxLockView"  VerticalAlignment="center">
            <Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Behaviors:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <Behaviors:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxLockView_SelectionChanged}"/>
                </Behaviors:EventTrigger>
           </Behaviors:Interaction.Triggers>
           <ListBoxItem x:Name="Lock" ToolTip="Vérouillage des vues">
               <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="lock"/>
           </ListBoxItem>
           <ListBoxItem x:Name="UnLock" ToolTip="Dévérouillage des vues">
               <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="UnlockedMinus"  />
           </ListBoxItem>
       </ListBox>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding MsgVues}" />
    </ToolBar>
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind `SelectedLockView` to your ListBox's [SelectedItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem):

```
<ToolBar Style="{DynamicResource MaterialDesignToolBar}" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <ListBox Height="50" x:Name="ListBoxLockView" VerticalAlignment="center" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLockView}">
       <ListBoxItem x:Name="Lock" ToolTip="Vérouillage des vues">
           <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="lock"/>
       </ListBoxItem>
       <ListBoxItem x:Name="UnLock" ToolTip="Dévérouillage des vues">
           <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="UnlockedMinus"  />
       </ListBoxItem>
   </ListBox>
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding MsgVues}" />
</ToolBar>
```

When you select an item in the ListBox, the binding will receive the newly selected item. In the `SelectedLockView` property setter code, you will get a [ListBoxItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.listboxitem) as the `value`. `SelectedLockView` should therefore be an Object or a ListBoxItem. If it is an Object, you can use `CType(value, ListBoxItem)` to convert it to a ListBoxItem. You can then get the name of the selected item:

```
Private _selectedItem As ListBoxItem

Public Property SelectedLockView As ListBoxItem
    Get
        Return _selectedItem
    End Get
    Set(value As ListBoxItem)
        _selectedItem = value
        MsgBox(_selectedItem.Name & " was selected.")
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realised that only "SelectedChanged" couldn't be binding.

Comment: @EldoctorSertato you could probably still use the SelectionChanged EventTrigger and use `{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListBoxLockView}` as the CommandParameter. Using a SelectedItem binding seems simpler to me.

Comment: @EtienneLanneville I've tried but I get this message:
the 'SelectionChanged' event can only be linked to properties whose type is 'SelectionChangedEventHandler'.